# Reading HDMI Input for Realtek RT1295

Tags: android, hdmi

I am building an app to read HDMI input from android boxes (Amlogic and Realtek processors) and display in my app.

I am aware that each different processors have different way to read HDMI input. For example with Amlogic, continuous HDMI stream can be read at hdmi://localhost:1/ and displayed in videoview. Certain other processors also follow a similar method and stream at one of (hdmi://localhost:0, hdmi://localhost:1, hdmi://localhost?port=1, hdmi://localhost?port=2) for developer to read the HDMI input stream.

Likewise, how do read HDMI input from Realtek RT1295  display it in my app? 
Also, are these the SDKs to HDMI input from RT1295 ([link](https://mega.nz/#!xM5jyYLB!jYiPP8beEp7vGM-3dFR2-U1BraeDVqlHA7OwrFHed3o)) ?

Comment: Hey, could you find any solution for this?